# Change PhpStorm boot runtime without opening PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a problem with PhpStorm. I work on Ubuntu (20?). I get the following  error when I try to open a project and PhpStorm closes:

> FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.

- I tried to set `ide.browser.jcef.gpu.disable = true` in registry.
- I tried disabling plugins but it doesn't help.
- I tried to remove plugins from `~/.local/share/JetBrains` folder.
- I've tried to change runtime JDK, but I couldn't.
- I could open PhpStorm only in LightEdit mode, but when I press Cmd + Shift + A and choose "Choose Boot Runtime for the IDE", nothing shows.

That's why I'm asking if is there any option to change JDK from outside of PhpStorm?

Could anyone help?

Comment: Have you try reinstall with latest version?

Comment: I reinstalled project and for now everything's working